# Get exact ID within thousands of concurrent transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, iis

I have a very crowd table with thousands of logs. Every time a new log is inserted in a database, I need to do update some tables using the ID of new log. So I get the last ID using these two lines of code:

```
objcon.execute "insert into logs (member,refer) values (12,12345)"
objcon.execute "select top 1 id from logs order by id desc"
```

I am afraid if the second line get another ID from a most recent order because there are thousands of new logs in one second.

This is a sample scenario and I know that there is built in methods to get the ID of recently inserted row. But my exact question is that if there is a logical order of transactions in a server (both IIS and SQL server) or it is possible that a new transaction finishes before an old transaction so the second line, get the ID of another log?

Comment: use `SCOPE_IDENTITY() ` and not `@@IDENTITY`. it will give you the correct identity

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely possible that your second query will get id from another transaction. I strongly suggest that you use SCOPE_IDENTITY(). These kind of methods are provided in DBMS just for this exact scenario where you insert a row and then do select the last row from that table, but in between these 2 operations other connections might have inserted new rows.

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY()  is the right way to go (not @@IDENTITY. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @SergeiZinovyev thanks for the information. I realised the mistake and corrected my answer.

Comment: @SergeiZinovyev . . . The "right" way to do this is the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: OR use the outputclause

Comment: @GordonLinoff Agreed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I actually upvoted your answer because I actually like your solution more than mine. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Concurrent transactions can cause problems with what you are trying to do.

The right solution is the [`output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause.  The code looks like this:

```
declare @ids table (id int);

insert into logs (member, refer)
    output inserted.id into @ids
    values (12, 12345);

select *
from @ids;
```

You can find multiple discussions on the web about why `OUTPUT` is better.  Here are some reasons:

1. You can return multiple columns, not just the identity.
2. It is session- and table- safe.
3. It handles multiple rows.
4. It is the same syntax for `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`.

Comment: OR SCOPE_IDENTITY ()

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a `WHERE` clause on the `SELECT` query, you would need to execute these queries in a transaction and under the `SNAPSHOT` isolation level before committing the changes. That way, only changes made by the current transaction are visible.

It would be better to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to return the last identity value generated in the outermost scope of current connection. This differs from `@@IDENTITY` in that the value is not affected by triggers that might also generate identify values.

```
objcon.execute "insert into logs (member,refer) values (12,12345)"
objcon.execute "select SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id;"
```